# Преобразование SQL запроса в запрос Yii2

Tags: sql, yii2

Здравствуйте, возникла необходимость преобразовать SQL запрос в запрос в Yii2. 
Делал по [мануалу](http://yiiframework.domain-na.me/doc/guide/2.0/ru/db-query-builder).

Сам SQL запрос выглядит так:

```
SELECT classroom_id, SUM( duration)  FROM schedule GROUP BY classroom_id
```

Я сделал в таком виде, все отлично работает:

```
$test = Schedule::findBySql("SELECT classroom_id, SUM( duration)  FROM schedule GROUP BY classroom_id")
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

Но я хотел бы его преобразовать в такой вид запрос:

```
$test = Schedule::find()
        ->select(["SUM('duration')", 'classroom_id'])
        ->from('schedule')
        ->groupBy('classroom_id')
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
```

Только не выходит получить такие же значения как в запросе через "findBySql". Поле "SUM('duration')" получает значение 0.

В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде так

```
$test = Schedule::find()
        ->select([new yii\db\Expression("SUM(duration)"), 'classroom_id'])
        ->from('schedule')
        ->groupBy('classroom_id')
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
```

Comment: Хм. Применение yii\db\Expression. 
Не подключает его. Сейчас разберусь.

Comment: добавьте обратный слеш, вот так \yii\db\Expression или пропишите use yii\db\Expression перед классом

Comment: Хм. Не помогает такое лекарство. В методе Expression должна обрабатываться функция суммы или весь аргумент селекта?

Comment: Сейчас как в документации попробую сделать.

Comment: @Anatoliy.CHA попробуйте одинарные ковычки убрать `SUM(duration)`

Comment: Мертвое дело без ковычек. 
По логам выдает, что такой функции вообще нет. Хоть подключил перед классом "use yii\db\Expression". В Yii2 есть такой класс (по пути yii\db\Expression) , но  "/**
     * @var string the DB expression
     */
    public $expression;"  это просто переменная.

Comment: @Anatoliy.CHA прошу прощения, добавьте `new` перед выражением `new yii\db\Expression("SUM(duration)")`

Comment: Во. Отлично. )
Чет сам протупил. Спасибо большое за помощь и потраченное время. )